How to import recent project history from old JetBrains Rider version?
I just updated my JetBrains Rider from 2023.1 to 2023.3.
The new version dropped all my recent projects history.
I have tried to import settings from old version, but there is no history option in export/import settings. Thus import settings from old version doesn't help.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Directories_Used_by_the_IDE_to_Store_Settings_Caches_Plugins_and_Logs.html#config-directory -- check the config folder for your OS (for that old version). Other IDEA-based IDEs have options/recentProjects.xml file -- this is where the recent projects are stored. See what Rider has for this.

@LazyOne Thanks! The file for Rider is recentSolutions.xml.
